# Can I use the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit in my MVC4 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've spent a fair amount of time researching this, as I would rather not find out through trial and error.

Can I use the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit in my MVC4 Application? Is there Microsft documentation that gives definitive information?

Yes, I know that MVC4 does not have VIEWSTATE. I am using the Razor view engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for the toolkit states specifically that it is for web forms, not mvc.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

If there is a specific piece of functionality you required, then you might want to see if there is a plugin available for jquery to replicate it.

http://api.jquery.com